# data frame writer overwrite the data in all Azure Datalake gen2 storage containers

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

In my Datalake storage account there is a one container which is having multiple folders and these folders contains files that which are being generated on a daily basis.

By accident someone writes the dataframe in the container only by below command.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option(mode,'overwrite').csv('mnt/container name')
```

No folder name was provided in the CSV file path which result in overwrite all the files which were already there in the container by _success,_commited and _vaccum files.

Is there any way I can restore the origiñal files or can undo what have been done.

Comment: do you have "Soft Delets" enabled on your ADLS storage account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-overview

Comment: Yes it is enabled. How can I restore the specific file?.